# Postgresql 13 64 bit and SSL

Tags: windows, ssl, postgresql-13

I have always used Postgresql Version 10, 32 bit with SSL, today I installed the Version 13, 64 bit, on a new Windows server and, if ssl is active, the service does not start anymore.
I copied, as always, the certificate files, server.crt and server.key in the DATA folder and I set, as I always did, the postgresql.conf file, but the service does not start and I have nothing useful in the logs . If I don't activate SSL, everything is fine.
This is the ssl part of the configuration:

```
ssl = on
ssl_ca_file = 'root.crt'
ssl_cert_file = 'server.crt'
ssl_crl_file = 'root.crt'//TESTED WITH OR WITHOUT
ssl_key_file = 'server.key'
#ssl_ciphers = 'HIGH:MEDIUM:+3DES:!aNULL' # allowed SSL ciphers
#ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = on
#ssl_ecdh_curve = 'prime256v1'
#ssl_min_protocol_version = 'TLSv1.2'
#ssl_max_protocol_version = ''
#ssl_dh_params_file = ''
#ssl_passphrase_command = ''
#ssl_passphrase_command_supports_reload = off
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have re-generated the certificates and now everything is fine.